# Setting up the default value in a new textbox

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to make a form in which there will be a button, when clicking on it a Javascript function will be called and a new row with a textbox will be added. In simple words, when clicking on the button, new text will be added. Here is the function:

```
function addRowToTable()

    {
      var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
      var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
      // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
      var iteration = lastRow;
      var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

      // left cell
      var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
      var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
      cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

      // right cell
      var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
      var el = document.createElement('input');
      el.type = 'text';
      el.name = 'txtRow' + iteration;
      el.id = 'txtRow' + iteration;
      el.size = 40;

      cellRight.appendChild(el);

      // select cell
      var cellRightSel = row.insertCell(2);
      var sel = document.createElement('select');
      sel.name = 'selRow' + iteration;
      sel.options[0] = new Option('text zero', 'value0');
      sel.options[1] = new Option('text one', 'value1');
      cellRightSel.appendChild(sel);
    }
```

Now please guide me: how can I set the default value of the text box and drop down box? I mean in this code where should I put `<?php echo $data['pno'];?>`

I have tried putting in the HTML form; for the first row it works but for the second row it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: So is the value for the textbox going to be fetched from the PHP script on creation via an ajax call?

Comment: yeah but then plz let me know if there is complete example of it because i dnt have much idea abt jquery .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have solved in this way

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRowToTable(<?php echo $data['pno'];?>);" />
```

and on the javascript side

```
function addRowToTable(a)
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
  var iteration = lastRow;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

  // left cell
  var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
  cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

  // right cell
  var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
  var el = document.createElement('input');

  el.type = 'text';
  el.value=a;   // here i have achived the value
  el.name = 'txtRow' + iteration; 
  el.id = 'txtRow' + iteration;
  el.size = 40;


}
```

might be its not a good solution but for my case it works

Answer (score 0):

How about you save the default value in a separate JS variable in your html like:

```
var defaultValue = "<?php echo $data['pno'];?>";
```

Or try this:

```
var defaultValue = "<?= $data['pno'] ?>";
```

Then when you are adding new `input` you can use it like this:

```
el.value = defaultValue;
```

Comment: i want to do it exactly but it doest work , might be php is for the server side

Comment: I added something else to it, do you see any errors in log? or warnings?

Comment: it displays the same <?= $data['pno'] ?> thing in the textbox